# Disable script after certain scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've posted it before but none got it what I need. I need to disable this script after certain scrolling page, let's say page is scrolled 30% this script is disabled.

The reason I need to disable this script is that after certain scrolling  div used in script is showed over some other div elements when page is scrolled, so I need to disable script after certain scrolling.

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 60) {
                $('.additional').css('position', 'fixed');
                $('.additional').css('top', 70);
            } else {
                $('.additional').css('position', 'relative');
                $('.additional').css('top', 0);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I won't answer because you never accept answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a working function in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewhaining/JbVH3/) with a dummy outcome, as you didn't provide any code of your page structure.

It calculates the scroll percentage using `$(window).scrollTop()` and `$(document).height()` and then uses an if/else statement to toggle two outcomes based on the result of the calculation.

```
function moveScroller() {

    var move = function () {

        var calc = $(window).scrollTop() / $(document).height();

        if (calc > 0.3) {
            /*EG:*/ $('#content').css('backgroundColor', '#f00');
            /*$('.additional').css('position', 'fixed');
            $('.additional').css('top', 70);*/
        } else {
            /*EG:*/ $('#content').css('backgroundColor', '#f0f');
            /*$('.additional').css('position', 'relative');
            $('.additional').css('top', 0);*/
        }

    };
    $(window).scroll(move);
    move();
}

$(function () {
    moveScroller();
});
```